# How does the file command distinguish text and LaTeX files?

Tags: files, text-formatting, text, file-command, file-types

I have a number of files (Jupyter notebooks, `.ipynb`) which are text files. All of these contain some LaTeX markup. But when I run `file`, I get:

```
$ file nb_*          
nb_1.ipynb:      ASCII text
nb_2.ipynb:      ASCII text
nb_3.ipynb:      ASCII text, with very long lines
nb_4.ipynb:      LaTeX document, ASCII text, with very long lines
nb_5.ipynb:      text, with very long lines
```

How does `file` distinguish these? I would like all files to have the same type.

---

(Why should the files have the same type? I am uploading them to an online system for sharing. The system classifies them somehow and treats them differently, with no possibility for me to change this. I suspect the platform uses `file` or maybe [libmagic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)#Libmagic_library) internally and would like to work around this.)

Comment: Have you tried the `--keep-going` option?

Comment: You can find the rules in, for example,`/usr/share/file/magic/*`; the actual location may vary depending on how `file` was packaged and/or installed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The file type recognition is driven by so-called *magic*
patterns. The [magic file for analyzing
*TeX*](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/tex)
family source code contains a number of macro names that cause
a file to be classified as *LaTeX*. Each match is assigned a
*strength*, e. g. 15 in case of `\begin` and 18 for
`\chapter`. This makes the heuristic more robust against
false positives like misclassification of Plain TeX or ConTeXt
documents that happen to define their own macros with those names.

Comment: `grep -i latex /usr/share/misc/magic` gets the specific patterns. Your magic file location may vary, of course. @cheersmate, you may be able to find a particular pattern or two in the "LaTeX" doc. Similarly, look for non-ASCII characters/bytes in the non-ASCII file (if it makes a difference).

Answer (score 2):

I found one string which seems to make `file` classify a file as LaTeX:

```
$ cat text
a
b
$ cat latex
a
\begin
b
$ file text latex
text:  ASCII text
latex: LaTeX document, ASCII text
```

So at least I can force all files to have the same type by adding some environments to the files currently classified as text.